# MAUI SearchBar Style

Tags: maui, searchbar

Is there a way to customize the style of the built in SearchBar in MAUI? I need a white background like the bottom image and remove the Cancel button.

My XAML:

```
<SearchBar Placeholder="Search" ios:SearchBar.SearchBarStyle="Minimal" BackgroundColor="White" />
```

Result:

[image]

Desired:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I need a white background like the bottom image and remove the Cancel
> button.

For white background, you can add property `BackgroundColor="White"` for your `SearchBar` .

For removing the Cancel button, you can try to use [Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-7.0) to achieve this.

Please refer to the following code:

```
    void ModifySearchBar() { 
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.SearchBarHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
            // handler.PlatformView.UpdateCancelButtonColor
#elif IOS || MACCATALYST

            handler.PlatformView.SetShowsCancelButton(false,false);

#elif WINDOWS

#endif
        });
```

**Note:**

1.Above code I used   `handler.PlatformView.SetShowsCancelButton(false,false);` to hide cancel button in IOS.

2.For more about how to use Handler in maui,you can check document: [Customize controls with handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize?view=net-maui-7.0).

Comment: BackgroundColor property="White" is already in my XAML, doesn't work. It only sets the "surrounding" color if SearchBarStyle="Default". Also the handler does not remove the cancel button. I can see the code is hit when setting a breakpoint there but it does not remove the cancel button. I have made a custom SearchBar instead.

Comment: Sorry,I don't have IOS device. I only tested on android, the code `BackgroundColor="White"`  works on android.

Comment: `I have made a custom SearchBar instead.` Could you please post your custom SearchBar here so that it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's just a simple grid with 3 columns containing an icon, entry and an iconbutton and a border surrounding it. My custom searchbar involves icon fonts, styling, autocomplete list, bindings, etc, to much to post here. The simple answer to my question is: Don't use the SearchBar, instead create a custom one. I am sure people can figure out how to do that themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your support for maui and sharing.  Have a nice day.